# How to track a program's disk usage over time?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, monitoring

In Windows 7, how can I track how much a program writes to disk over a period of time?

For example, if I wanted to see how much Firefox writes to disk in a 24-hour period, how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that Firefox process continues to run (you don't close it and it does not quit), you can start Task Manager (`taskman.exe`), switch to processes tab, then in menu `View` -> `Select columns` enable `I/O Read Bytes` and `I/O Write Bytes`.

Now, simply look at I/O read and write bytes columns for process `firefox.exe` - it will tell you how much data Firefox has read or written since it was started, something like this:

[image]

You can also write your own Windows program to get the same information by using Win32 API function [GetProcessIoCounters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Are I/O bytes *only* bytes written to disk, and not written to memory? And are these bytes all-inclusive of any/all possible bytes that Firefox has written to drive, or is it only bytes written to the pagefile (for example)?

Comment: @Coldblackice: I/O write bytes should mean actual disk I/O - like writing to or reading from files or databases. I am not sure if pagefile access is counted against Firefox or against global system. Normally, page file is almost never used (if it is, your system would work very slow). However, some indicative whether this is happening would be looking at "Page Faults" column. If it was 0, that means paging did not happen.